# How can I separate a long path into multiple lines?

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to separate a long path to multiple lines, like this:

```
cd foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4/bar
```

to

```
cd foo1\
   foo2\
   foo3\
   foo4\
   bar
```

Comment: Did you want the backslashes (\\) to turn into forward slashes (`/`) automatically?

Comment: yes but Backlash and antislash give me errore : cd: too many arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do this with an array but the `cd` command looks a bit complicated:

```bsh
path=(
    foo1
    foo2
    foo3
    foo4
    bar
)
cd "$(IFS=/; echo "${path[*]}")"
```

Array literals allow for arbitrary whitespace.

Comment: that is better for indente, can you explain IFS meen

Comment: The `"$*"` and `"${array[*]}"` forms, when in double quotes, join all the elements into a single string, joined by the first character of the IFS variable. IFS is, by default, "space tab newline", so I redefine it in the subshell to hold the directory separator.

Comment: wow, i see some Magic here, it's perfect Mr @glenn-jackman

Comment: donc ,you are using IFS to trim whitespace ? and converte to "/"

Comment: The array contains 5 elements with no extra whitespace. You can inspect the array using `declare -p path`. `"${path[*]}"` joins the elements into a single string using `/`, the first character of IFS.

Answer (score 11):

You can separate a long command into multiple lines by using backslashes, but you would need to preserve the forward-slashes and omit the leading spaces:

```
cd foo1\
/foo2\
/foo3\
/foo4\
/bar
```

The backslashes are a line-continuation marker; when bash sees them, it incorporates the next line as if it was continued at the backslash of the current line. As a result, you couldn't use leading spaces on those subsequent lines, since they'd become spaces on the current line, creating a "too many arguments" error.

Comment: i like it , but can i have indent

Comment: @AyoubElMhamdi No you can't have an indent.

Comment: thank you so mush @JeffSchaller